# Stop expansion of player (e.g. spotify, website, etc)

Tags: android-11, spotify, quick-settings

We all know that google has no idea about ux or ui, but I am hoping someone on their end is smart enough to give us an option, that I am just incapable of finding in their settings mess.

android 11, oxygen os 11.0.3.1.hd65aa

Here's the quick low down. In the notification bar, spotify sits above notifications, where the quick actions are. I'm ok with this, even though the player is imo larger than it needs to be. The real issue is when I expand my quick actions. Now spotify becomes fucking huge. There's no need for this to happen. I would like to keep it small. I am talking specifically about this:

[image]

[image]

It leaves very little room for notifications, and collapsing it all again is a nuisance too.

Comment: [That is the designed behavior from Android 11](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/playing-nicely-with-media-controls.html?m=1) //You can raise a ticket with Google if you want this to be changed //nothing can be offered by the community here

Comment: @beeshyams thanks for that information. This is sad news indeed. Google doesn't care about its users, as is obvious by the net negative user experience changes in android, chrome, gmail, etc, but I appreciate the full response.